# How to optimise the 'XQuery' SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery-sql

I have an XML hierarchy like this in an XML type column of a table with 10,000 records-

```
<Root>
     <Elem1>
         <Parent1>
              <Separator>
                  <Child1/>
              </Separator>
         </Parent1>
     </Elem1>
</Root>
```

---

I have a query like this -

```
DECLARE @Root VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Entity VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ParentNode VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Separator VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ChildNode VARCHAR(50)


SET @Root = 'Root'
SET @Entity = 'Elem1'
SET @ParentNode = 'Parent1'
SET @Separator = 'separator'
SET @ChildNode = 'Child1'

select Parent.P.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as MyValue, 
T.uniqueId, T.XMLCol
from [XMLTable] as T
cross apply 
 (SELECT
         XMLTable.XMLCol.query('(/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@Root")]/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@Entity")]/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@ParentNode")]/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@Separator")]/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@ChildNode")])[1]'
 )  as Parent(P)
```

How can I further Optimize this query. Currently, it is taking 2 secs and if I do further INNER JOINS, it adds up to the time. I tried creating a PRIMARY Index on the XML Column, but it takes more time !

**EDIT- If I hardcode the path instead of using variables, then it takes less than a second. But, I want it in a Table-Valued function and cannot hardcode path ?**

---

### EDIT - Solution

```
select x.value('(Parent1/Separator1/Child1)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Col1,
x.value('(Parent2/Separator2/Child2)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Col2,
x.value('(Parent3)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Col3
from [XMLTable] T 
cross apply T.XMLCOL.nodes('/Root/Elem1') a(x)
```

The above query takes just about **one sec**. It seems to be the fastest of all. So, instead of going for a Table valued function with params, the above query can be dynamically prepared  and executed on the fly using [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971534.aspx) capabilities

Correct me please ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one value out of every row there is no need to use `cross apply`.

```
select XMLCol.value('(/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@Root")]
                      /*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@Entity")]
                      /*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@ParentNode")]
                      /*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@Separator")]
                      /*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@ChildNode")])[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from XMLTable
```

Another way to get the same is to use [FLWOR](http://wwww.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_flwor.asp). In my limited tests this will run a bit faster.

```
select XMLCol.value('(for $n1 in /*,
                          $n2 in $n1/*,
                          $n3 in $n2/*,
                          $n4 in $n3/*,
                          $n5 in $n4/*
                      where $n1[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Root")] and
                            $n2[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Entity")] and
                            $n3[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@ParentNode")] and
                            $n4[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Separator")] and
                            $n5[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@ChildNode")]
                      return $n5
                     )[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from XMLTable
```

Comment: There is a gain of 2 secs using the FLOWR. Thanks for that. Still, I need to get it down. Soon, will post an update.

Comment: @SeeSharp - Sure. I see no wrong with that. If you can build the query dynamically it will be faster than searching the XML with local-name().

Comment: Thanks Mikael. Your suggestions really rock ! Have learnt a lot. Thanks for contributing like this to the community.