# Using XQuery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

My table contains 2 columns, one is the `Id` of type `int` and the other is of type `Xml`.

In the `Xml` column, I have data of this structure

```
<Fields>
    <Field name='aa' value='000'/>
    <Field name='bb' value='111'/>
    <Field name='cc' value='222'/>
</Fields>
```

Now using XQuery, I want to query the table to get all rows where field tag with name attribute is `aa` and value attribute is `111`, AND field tag with name is attribute `bb` and value attribute is `222`.

In other words I want to supply the name / value pair and get rows where the xml data match.

Thank you !

Comment: To do that you need to use the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx). Give it a try and ask a new question when you run into trouble.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7064207/763026

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this (since you didn't mention your table or column names, I just used something on my own - adapt those as needed!):

```
SELECT 
    (list of columns)
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
WHERE 
    XmlContent.exist('/Fields/Field[@name = "aa"][@value = "000"') = 1
```

This would return all rows from your table where the XML contains a `<Field>` node with attributes `name = "aa"` and `value = "000"`

Comment: Thanks! But I want to return not just for a name value pair. That is,I want where name is aa and value is 000 AND name is  bb  and value is 222. Thanks for your promt response

Comment: Thanks! But I want to return not just for a name value pair. That is,I want all rows  where there exists a field node with attribute name name is 'aa' and value is '000' AND  and another field node with attribute name 'bb' and value is '222'. Thanks for your prompt

Comment: @otubuOlukayode: in that case, just add `AND XmlContent.exist('/Fields/Field[@name = "bb"][@value = "222"') = 1` to the `WHERE` clause of that query I posted